# Change signature of open e-mail with Apple Script

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

I have the following Apple Script:

```
tell application "Mail"
    make new outgoing message with properties {message signature:(signature named "MyTestSignature")}
    activate
end tell
```

This will open a new e-mail window and change the signature to the pre-defined signature called `MyTestSignature`.

But I don't want Apple Script to create a new window. Instead I want Apple Script to change the signature of the e-mail that's already open and in the foreground.

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @nohillside I played around with the script above but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution myself.

Here's the working code:

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        click pop up button "Signatur:" of window 1
        click menu item "Test-Signatur" of menu 1 of pop up button "Signatur:" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

**ATTENTION**: This is German language. You'll have to change `Signatur:` (two times in code, and don't forget the colon) to your language, depending on how the button is called in your Apple Mail app. Also you need to replace `Test-Signatur` by the exact name of the signature you want to select.

[image]